# unclosed quotation mark after the character string sql server

Tags: sql-server, visual-c++

I'm trying to get my update command in SQL to work. Every time I try to update a record I get the following error unclosed quotation mark after the character string. Here my code:

```
String^ connectionString = L"**********"; 
SqlConnection^ myCon = gcnew SqlConnection(connectionString);

SqlCommand^ myCommand = gcnew SqlCommand("UPDATE ******* SET Customer_Name = '" + this -> txtName -> Text + "', Customer_Address = '" + this -> txtPhone -> Text + "', Customer_City = '" + this -> txtCity -> Text + "', Customer_State = '" + this -> txtState -> Text + "', Customer_Zip = '" + this -> txtZip -> Text + "', Customer_Phone = '" + this -> txtPhone -> Text + "', Customer_Email = '" + this -> txtEmail -> Text + "' where Customer_Name = '" + this -> txtName -> Text + ",);", myCon);
SqlDataReader^ myReader;

try {
       myCon -> Open();
       myReader = myCommand -> ExecuteReader();
       MessageBox::Show("Updated!!");
}
catch (Exception^ ex) {
    MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
}
```

I am not sure how to fix this error. Any help would be great.

Comment: Perhaps you're using the wrong language? Because the code you showed is not valid C++.

Comment: That' s not C++ (and nothing I know) But the ` where Customer_Name = '" + this -> txtName -> Text + ",);"` looks suspicious. The single quote of `Customer_Name='` isn't closed.

Comment: Sorry the code is visual C++. I have used the same code before in a different program and it worked. The only difference between the two program is the first I used MySQL and this program in using just SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have an error in your query. There is a missing quotation mark on the `where` part.

Instead of

```
"' where Customer_Name = '" + this -> txtName -> Text + "**,);**"
```

you should write

```
"' where Customer_Name = '" + this -> txtName -> Text + "**';**"
```

Comment: Yes that fixed it. Thank you.